# MIX RGBs not working

Tags: uv, shaders, camera, shader-nodes

I'm struggling with something, as I am following a tutorial on youtube.

**Lightning Boy Studio** made a **wonderful video** on how to imitate Arcane's style in blender using camera projection and several UV mapping. Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gG7ZoP3fd1w&t=879s

( Timing from 4:50 to 15:00 ).

I believe I really have followed the instructions to the letters yet, Lightning boy studio's results are different. So I am clearly missing something, and I'd appreciate any help. Here is a link to my project : https://we.tl/t-imUCu1TiIf

I have made the two projected textures look very different, with each face marked with a number to diagnose more easily where the issue lies. ***The front projected texture*** is a ***bright red*** with a number on each face ( from 1 to 3 ). ***The back facing*** projection is ***bright blue*** with the faces numbered from 1 to 2.
Here is the very simple shading setup.

2 textures, mixed together with an RGB mix node. A UV map node on the second texture set to another UV projection, using the alpha on the second texture to limit how much of the 2nd projection we see.
[image: Here is the very simple shading setup]

Here is the unfortunate result :[image]

So clearly the limitation of the alpha channel isn't working. I thought the issue lied with my texture lacking an alpha. But I tried a PNG image with pure b&w instead of using the alpha channel, and still the masking didn't take place. So the issue is somewhere else.

I have made an extra effort to make sure I had 2 different sets of UV mapping, that are very different.[image][image]

I named them "front" and "back" for more clarity. The camera the view they are projected from bare the same name.

The only difference I saw between my project and the tutorial I follow was the blender version. I use 3.1.2 while the tutorial uses 3.0. So installed the older version, and still the same issue persists.

I'm out of ideas, if you guys have any thoughts to share I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I didn't have a look at the tutorial, just your node tree. I think in the image texture nodes you have to change ```repeat``` to ```clip``` because if the texture is repeating there won't be any alpha, but when it is set to ```clip``` everything outside the image is transparent. And if there is no transparency your mixRGB node will only pass on the bottom image texture.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering ! Unfortunately, that didn't change anything ! But again, thank you for trying.

Comment: Can you prove an image of your UV maps?

Comment: For sure ! Here they are !
 https://ibb.co/wyXLHKZ


https://ibb.co/g9pRvmq

Comment: Here I also added them to the description, so it's easier for everyone to see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies within your textures:
[image]
Your Textures cover the whole cube but in the tutorial they don't:

[image]

As you can see in the tutorial, there is only one face covered with texture, the rest is transparent and that is where the other texture will appear, but since your texture covers the whole cube, there is no transparency on the cube (only around it) and thus you don't see the second texture. to fix this you will have to change the textures like so:
[image]

Which gives you this result:

[image]

But as you might notice, in the UV Maps, take for example the face Front 3, there are other faces overlapping, like the bottom face or the one in the back right. This is why the texture is not only appearing on that one face but also other ones. To fix that you can change the UV map like so:

In edit mode, select all the faces that are not visible from the cameras perspective:

[image]

And move them to a transparent area in your UV-editor:

[image]

(Notice that the two faces, you want the texture on are still aligned with the texture)

This will give you the result you want, although it is not following the tutorial exactly:

[image]

Comment: OMG, omg OMG THIS IS AMAZING ! I'm SUCH a dumb ass ! Thank you THANK YOU !!!